# css positioning different styles of text in a div

Tags: css, html

This doesn't seem that difficult...  I've just got 3 types of styles of text in a div that I need to place them all with pinpoint accuracy.
fonttest3.css

```
h1 {
    font-size: 41px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
} 


h2 {
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    color: #FF9980;
    margin-top: 40px; padding-top: 5px;
    text-indent: 10px; 
} 


h3 {
    clear: both;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;     
    color: #B5B3DA;  
    text-align:left;  
     vertical-align: 20px     
} 



#topright {
  width: 797px ;
  height: 141px;
        background-color: White;  
    float: left;
}




body {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
        background-color: #000000;
}
```

fonttest3.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>test</title>
  <meta name="description" content="test">
  <meta name="author" content="Algomeysa">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonttester3.css">
</head>

<body>



<div id="topright">
<h1>SPACELY SPROCKETS</h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<h2>INCORPORATED</h2>
<h3>Doing that thing we do since 2025 for residential, commercial, and institutional clients</H3>
</div>
<

</body>
</html>
```

This works reasonably well in Chrome and Firefox, but I'd want to move the bottom line up a bit, and playing with vertical-align seems to get me nowhere.

But it's horrendous in IE9, which makes me think I should be using an entirely different method to format this text.     Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    font-size: 41px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    line-height: 43px;
} 


h2 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    color: #FF9980;
    line-height: 43px;
}
```

Hope This help You :)

Comment: Thanks, with a few <BR>s it's closer to what I'm trying to do.     The way it iines up in Internet Explorer it still weird, though not at catastrophic as the earlier attempt.